# Cycles not working in the viewport with GPU

Tags: cycles-render-engine

When I have cycles set to using my CPU it loads in fine, but when I have it set to my GPU none of the colors textures or lighting render in.

Comment: If you're experiencing a bug in Blender, please read [this guide](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports/173685#173685) and create a bug report on the official bug tracker. Either way we need more information and a question in order to give you an answer, both here and on the bug tracker.

Comment: Well idk if it's a bug, I'm trying to see if it's something in the settings that I need to turn on. I have Open Cl enabled for the GPU and it was working last week. I haven't changed anything.

Comment: Can you please post of a screenshot of the entire UI with the settings that work and those that don't? No matter if you set the CPU or GPU as render device, when selecting the rendered mode for the viewport they should show the same result, with textures.

Comment: They don't show the same, the CPU shows the lighting and colors and everything and the GPU just shows blank I will upload two different screenshots showing what I mean.

Comment: ok here's a link: https://imgur.com/a/8xBQtiE. The top is CPU, the bottom is GPU. I let it stay there while I ate dinner so about 30 minutes, it said that it was rendering and it may take a few minutes but at most, it has only taken at 5 minutes before but it didn't even load when I left it for a 30 mins today. Cycles was working with my GPU last week and I haven't downloaded any updates or anything until today when I tried fixing stuff, I downloaded driver and blender updates. GPU is 5700XT which is listed as supported. I have it enabled it preferences under Open CL.

Comment: Perhaps there has been an automatic driver update and there's an issue with the most recent version or an OS update causes problems? This is just a guess. You could try to manually install an older driver version and see if that fixes the problem.